# How to hide date time x-axis but still be able to show plot lines in Highcharts gantt chart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, axis, gantt-chart

I want to disable or hide marked x-axis on the following image:

[image]

But I still need to be able to show a plot line.

I tried to play around with "xAxis" Highcharts property and I am able to hide marked x-axis, but then I can not add a plot line. It seems to me this axis is somehow connected with the plot.

Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: You can use following JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/gantt/demo/interactive-gantt/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `plotLines` are connected to an axis, but you can separately disable the `grid` and the `labels`:

```
xAxis: [{
    ...,
    grid: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotLines: [{
        color: 'red',
        value: today + day * 7,
        width: 5
    }],
    labels: {
        enabled: false
    },
    tickLength: 0
}, {
    visible: false
}]
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/c2xLruvp/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/gantt/xAxis.visible